# Why my Panasonic KX-MB2030 starts printing blank pages?

Tags: printer, laser-printer

My Panasonic laser printer starts printing blank pages. Same issue after I replaced drum and toner. What could it be?

Comment: Are these pages that are supposed to contain printed content, or extra pages that are empty?

Comment: If you print a test page from the printer's front panel, is that blank?

Comment: No extra pages. Printing test page from printer's front panel, I also got one blank page.

Comment: About all I can think of for now are things like faulty laser, no EHT, paper blocking laser path, etc. However, the printer should detect those and show error messages for them. Is it under warranty?